# How to equal php answer?(.equals not working)

Tags: java

I have an error, I can't equal a variable. Here is my code:

```
        String answer = excuteGet("http://cruel-world.com/launcher/versions.php" + "?client=" + client[nameId] + "&version=" + client[versId], "");
        System.out.println(answer);
        if (answer.equals("OK")){
            System.out.println("fine");
        }
```

My script answer: OK, but if block not working.

Comment: whats the exact question??

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking**  
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely case here can be that the answer has leading/trailing white spaces. You need to `trim()` those out.

```
if (answer.trim().equals("OK")) {
```

---

You did not initially mention in the question that the answer had extra string besides "OK". In that case, you either need to remove other stuffs(using a regex may be), or use the `contains()` method to check if the answer string contains "OK" in it.

```
if (answer.contains("OK")) { // check if answer contains the string "OK"
```

Comment: Not working, here is my php answer block: $answer = "OK";

Comment: @Salim - Check the edit in the answer.

Comment: Awww, thanks, i need wait 5 mins for accept the answer, sorry me for my bad english.